# How to reset CheckBox buttonDrawable to default

Tags: android, android-layout, android-checkbox

When I add a CheckBox to a layout it has some button drawable assigned by default, particularly Android Studio shows it in the attributes pannel as

```
button: @android:drawable/btn_check_material_anim
```

If I change it to some other drawable, how can I reset it back to the default one programmically?

Comment: please , I need more details if it possible

Comment: how to clear CheckBox `button` attibute programically?

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong. You want a first state drawable when you click second time??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit 1: to support lower api level ( < 23) use this:

```
val compatBak = CompoundButtonCompat.getButtonDrawable(cb)
// cb is your CheckBox
```

> Edit: *Backing up* the `ButtonDrawable`:

To set the default attribute, we'll store default attribute somewhere, before changing it (avoid changing it in `xml`, as you can change it dynamically & it'll allow you to make a backup), (annotate `onCreate()` with `@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)` and save it before changing, later on you can use it.

```
val bak = cb.buttonDrawable
// re setting..
cb.buttonDrawable = bak;
```

or in Java:

```
CheckBox cb = findViewById(R.id.cb);
Drawable buttonDrawable = null;
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    buttonDrawable = cb.getButtonDrawable();
}

// later on.. 
cb.setButtonDrawable(buttonDrawable);
```

---

End of edit

I assume you're asking to change/set the `android:button` attribute of your `CheckBox`.
Here's how you can do it programmatically:

View:

```
 <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:button="@drawable/cb_drawable" />
```

Activity:

If you're using java:

```
CheckBox cb = findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
cb.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.cb_drawable);
```

Or in kotlin:

```
val cBox = findViewById<CheckBox>(R.id.checkBox)
cBox.buttonDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.cb_drawable)

// or just use synthetic
checkBox.buttonDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.cb_drawable)
```

`ContextCompat` or you can use `getDrawable()`. Here  `R.drawable.cb_drawable` is the desired `drawable` we want to set. Make `cb_drawable.xml` under the `drawable` folder.

Comment: the question is about how to reset to `system default` value, i.e. to absense of custom value.

Comment: is there a way to make it work for API 21-22 as well?

Comment: happy coding :-)